# Using Python, how to remove keywords that not match with text file?

Tags: python

How to remove keywords that not match with text file?

As an example, below is the text file that contains a list of keywords that need to be retained

vocab.txt

```
C++ 
Language
JavaScript
Git
C
React
Express.js
Node.js
TypeScript
```

doc_complete

```
["Candidate must possess at least Diploma/Advanced/Higher/Graduate Diploma, Bachelor's Degree/Post Graduate Diploma/Professional Degree, Master's Degree in Engineering (Computer/Telecommunication), Computer Science/Information Technology or equivalent.\nRequired language(s):\xa0English\nAt least 2\xa0Year(s) of working experience in the related field is required for this position.\nRequired Skill(s): C++ Language, JavaScript, Git, C, React, Express.js, Node.js, TypeScript\nPreferably Senior Manager specialized in IT/Computer - Software or equivalent."]
```

Desired output

```
[[ "C++", "JavaScript", "Git", "C", "React", "Express.js", "Node.js", "TypeScript"]]
```

Code

```
input = open("vocab.txt","w")

def clean(doc):
    output = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i in input])
    return output

file = open("doc_clean.txt", "w")

doc_clean = [clean(doc).split() for doc in doc_complete]  
file.write(str(doc_clean))
```

Comment: What issue did you run into?

Comment: I didn't get the target output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works:

```
with open('vocab.txt') as file:
    keywords = [x.strip() for x in file.readlines()]

with open("doc_clean.txt", "w") as file:
    filtered_words = [x for x in doc.split(' ') if x.replace(',','') in keywords]
    clean_doc = ' '.join(filtered_words)
    file.write(clean_doc)
```

First, we load the keywords file into a list called `keywords`. After that we filter the words in the document based if they are in the keywords list or not. The rest is formatting and writing back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Some weird errors in your code. I'll try to address them all.

1. You open `vocab.txt` in writing mode. That will instantly *kill* the text file and sets its size to zero bytes.
2. `input = open("..`: `input` is a useful function in Python and best left alone. Use any other name.
3. `.. if i in input`, while you only opened the file as yet (with the correction to *read*, not *write*), is asking a bit too much from Python since you haven't actually read anything from it. True, `for i in input` *will* read line by line from the file, but it will only do so *once*. Read the entire file first.
4. `output = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i in input])` is rather a good line (after the above fixes), but you are asking too much from `split`. It only splits on whitespace, but since in the text all of your keywords actually end with a comma, none of them will be found.
5. `.. [clean(doc).split() for doc in doc_complete]`: you do not show complete code, so is `doc_complete` actually an iterable list of data? I got the idea it's just a single document.
6. `str(doc_clean)` will not convert the *string* that you create in `create_doc` to a Python-like representation – it's *already* a string. So don't use `join` in that function if you actually want a list.
7. With all that fixed, you still have no results at all. That is because you compare your list against a *lowercase* version of the document – but all of your keywords contain one or more uppercase characters. So it won't actually match *anything* at all.

```py
doc_complete = '''["Candidate must possess at least Diploma/Advanced/Higher/Graduate Diploma, Bachelor's Degree/Post Graduate Diploma/Professional Degree, Master's Degree in Engineering (Computer/Telecommunication), Computer Science/Information Technology or equivalent.\nRequired language(s):\xa0English\nAt least 2\xa0Year(s) of working experience in the related field is required for this position.\nRequired Skill(s): C++ Language, JavaScript, Git, C, React, Express.js, Node.js, TypeScript\nPreferably Senior Manager specialized in IT/Computer - Software or equivalent."]'''

inp = open("vocab.txt","r").read().lower().split('\n')

def clean(doc):
    output = [i for i in doc.lower().replace(',', ' ').split() if i in inp]
    return output

doc_clean = clean(doc_complete)
print(str(doc_clean))
```

results in this:

```
['language', 'javascript', 'git', 'c', 'react', 'express.js', 'node.js', 'typescript']
```